# updating data in a file

Tags: python, file, writefile

I'm trying to write a code to do the following:
I have a text file named students, each line(record) has: id,name,grade,number and gpa
i'm trying to update the file and change the gpa(according to what the user enters in another function) I need first to find the id number of the student and then change his gpa.. When I'm using the write function, it's writing only the first line and the other lines get erased.. i'm not sure where is the problem.. any help is appreciated..

```
    file6=open("students.txt", 'r')
    students=[]
    for line3 in file6:
        students=line3.split(",")
        students[4]=students[4].rstrip('\n')
        if students[0]==str(x):
            gpa=str(gpa)
            del students[4]
            students.insert(4,gpa)
            print(students)
            for lines in file6:
                f=open("students.txt" ,'w')
                f.write(str(students[0])+',')
                f.write(str(students[1])+',')
                f.write(str(students[2])+',')
                f.write(str(students[3])+',')
                f.write(str(students[4])+'\n')
            break
```

Comment: That's the way files work.  If you want to change a file, you need to read the entire contents into memory, make your changes, and write it back out.  Think about how it would work if what you're writing is larger than what's there.  Fortunately, as a CSV file, it's easy to read it all in to a list of rows.  Create a "readit" method and a "writeit" method.

Comment: Thank u for replying .. How can i change a specific line that match the id then write it all ?

Comment: The same way you did it above.  You'd collect the lines into a larger list, changing the one you need to change, then rewind and write the whole thing back out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each function should have one well-defined role.  Then, you can combine and reuse them in many different ways.

```
def read_all(fn="students.txt"):
    students=[]
    for line in open(fn,'r'):
        students.append(line.strip().split(","))
    return students

def write_all(rows, fn="students.txt"):
    f = open(fn,'w')
    for row in rows:
        print( ','.join(row), file=f )

def replace_gpa(rows, key, gpa):
    for row in rows:
        if row[0] == key:
            row[4] = gpa
            return

data = read_all()
replace_gpa( "123", 4.0 )
write_all( data )
```

It would be even better to use the CSV module for this.

```
import csv

def read_all(fn="students.txt"):
    students=[]
    for row in cvs.reader(open(fn)):
        students.append(row)
    return students

def write_all(rows, fn="students.txt"):
    with cvs.writer(open(fn,'w')) as fcsv:
        fcsv.writerows( rows )

def replace_gpa(rows, key, gpa):
    for row in rows:
        if row[0] == key:
            row[4] = gpa

data = read_all()
replace_gpa( "123", 4.0 )
write_all( data )
```

Comment: thank you for replying.. so if i want to change my code to make it write the file all over again with the changes and keeping the other data.. what should i change ?

Comment: Did you read ANY of my answer?  I showed you how you do it.  You read in the whole file contents.  My code does exactly what your code did, except mine works.  You manipulate the contents as a Python data structure.  Then you write out the contents when finished.